# Should the commit_on_success decorator be used only in views in Django?

Tags: django, transactions

I'm looking at examples for the commit_on_success decorator in the Django website,

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Is it supposed/preferable to use this in views or can it be used with any function that does DB transactions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See that commit_on_success has been [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#features-deprecated-in-1-6) in Django 1.6. You should use the `@transaction.atomic` decorator instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to use `commit_on_success` for functions that aren't views. At my company we use it in many utility scripts.

Just make sure you don't 'nest' functions using the transaction decorators, as in the example below, otherwise you may get behaviour you weren't expecting.

```
# avoid doing the following!
@transaction.commit_on_success
def my_func()
    do_stuff()

@transaction.commit_on_success
def my_view()
    my_func()
```